# subprocess.popen returning empty string

Tags: json, subprocess, popen

There was an earlier question on this, but the asker was just overwriting their output and solved their own problem.

I'm using a subprocess.popen to read video information and write the output to a json. It works fine on MOST videos, but on others is returning an empty string on others - even though it runs fine from the command line.  I tried it several times and am getting the data fine through the command line.

Here's the relevant part of the script:

out_prj.write('[')

```
for m, i in enumerate(files):

        print i

        out_prj.write('{"$type":"BatchProcessor.Job, BatchProcessor","Id":0,"Ver":1.02,"CurrentTask":0,"IsSelected":true,"TaskList":[')
        f_name = os.path.basename(i[0])
        f_json = out_folder + os.sep + "06_Output" + os.sep + os.path.basename(i[0]).split(".")[0] + ".json"
        trans_f = out_folder + os.sep + "04_Video" + os.sep + os.path.basename(i[0]).split(".")[0] + "-tr.ts"
        trans_f_out = out_folder + os.sep + "06_Output" + os.sep + os.path.basename(i[0]).split(".")[0] + "-tr-out.ts"
        ffprobe = 'ffprobe.exe'
        command = [ffprobe, '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_format', '-show_streams', i[0]]



        p = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, shell=True)

        out, err = p.communicate()
        io = cStringIO.StringIO(out)
        info = json.load(io)
        print info
        filea = open(f_json, 'w')
        filea.write(json.dumps(info))
        filea.close()

        f = open(f_json)
        b = json.load(f)
        print b
        #########################

        ###################
        f_format = str(b['streams'][0]['codec_long_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ignores error messages (`err` variable). `print err` or don't redirect stderr to see them.

Unrelated: the json handling in your code is insane: most operations are redundant.

To save output of the subprocess to a file:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

f_json = os.path.join(out_folder, "06_Output",
                      os.path.splitext(f_name)[0] + ".json")
with open(f_json, 'wb', 0) as file:
    check_call(command, stdout=file)
```

Note: `shell=True` is not necessary here. If `subprocess` can't find `ffprobe.exe` then specify the full path e.g. (use the path appropriate for your system):

```
ffprobe = r'C:\Program Files\Real\RealPlayer\RPDS\Tools\ffmpeg\ffprobe.exe'
```

Note: `r''` -- a raw string literal is used to avoid doubling the backslashes.